# How to Change the Material of a Single particle (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

Hi I want to change the color of a single particle.
I used one Method, but it changes all particles.

Comment: Well do you mean _"material"_ or _"color"?_   I assume you mean _color._  If so you do it right there in the Editor.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that one cannot change the color of individual particle easily.
From this [docs page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Particle-startColor.html) on start color of particle:

"The current color of the particle is calculated procedurally based on this value and the active color modules."

Perhaps you can use a layered particle system. Not an expert on this.